# jQuery each return same result

Tags: jquery

i try to make an jquery template but i stuck in the middle of jQuery each. here's my code:

```
var json = [{"threadid":"1","username":"dvsdvs"},{"threadid":"32","username":"rgfedvre"}];
var template = '<li id="thread_{threadid}">{username}</li>';
 jQuery.each(json, function(index, value) {
  jQuery.each(value, function(subindex, subvalue) {
   template = template.replace('{' + subindex + '}', value[subindex]);
  });
 $(template).appendTo('body');
});
```

but the result is always

```
<li id="thread_1">dvsdvs</li>
<li id="thread_1">dvsdvs</li>
```

i would like to get some help, thanks.

Comment: General form is `jQuery(selector).each(...)` rather than `jQuery.each(selector, ...)`.

Comment: You are replacing the `{threadid}` in your `template` on the first loop iteration.  The 2nd iteration, it's already been replaced.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: `jQuery(selector).each(...)` is *only* for jQuery objects/DOM elements.  `jQuery.each(selector, ...)` is correct here, since he's using an array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Too quick to comment - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either start with a fresh template each time (so there are placeholders available), or replace into a temporary variable, and append that:

```js
var json = [{"threadid":"1","username":"dvsdvs"},{"threadid":"32","username":"rgfedvre"}];

var template = '<li id="thread_{threadid}">{username}</li>';

jQuery.each(json, function(index, value) {
  var t = template;
   
  jQuery.each(value, function(subindex, subvalue) {
    t = t.replace('{' + subindex + '}', value[subindex]);
  });
   
  $(t).appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Definitely prefer this option as it's more applicable to moving the template elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Logic error. You overwrote your original template on the first pass through the loop, then on the second pass it was unable to find the placeholders. Simply re-define your template on each iteration.

```js
var json = [{"threadid":"1","username":"dvsdvs"},{"threadid":"32","username":"rgfedvre"}];
jQuery.each(json, function(index, value) {
    var template = '<li id="thread_{threadid}">{username}</li>';
    jQuery.each(value, function(subindex, subvalue) {
        template = template.replace('{' + subindex + '}', subvalue);
    });
    $(template).appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```